# Android: seekbar.setProgress() gives Nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, seekbar

I have used `seekbar` like quite a few times but never faced problem. Yesterday I was dealing with Fragments which I am not too familiar with but implemented successfully. But at the end of the day when I included seekbar to the fragment and problems started. Not sure this is coz of fragments or what. Here is my code.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout>
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentMain.java

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

final static String TAG = "FragmentMain";
TextView mainTextView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seek);
    seekBar.setProgress(40);

    return view;
}
}
```

This FragmenMain is the center page of my viewPager.

I dont know why my code is crashing giving `NullPointerException` at `setProgress`.

*Feel free to suggest edits.*

Comment: The question has been marked duplicate comparing it with a question with a very broad aspect. I obviously know what nullPointerException means. I was not able to spot it here. Comeon! @Blackbelt

Comment: That's  the question I use for every NPE related questions. I could I agree on the fact that's slightly different in your case, but really your fragment related NPE question has been asked over and over again in the past. When you get a null reference from findViewById, it is always because you are looking for it in the wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seek);
```

You need to find the view with the parent view which your inflating not with context, replace it with

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. Can you explain why context didn't work?

Comment: because your inflating you layout with view, so it has the access to the contents of the layout, in fragments you will always find the views with the view your inflating your layout

Comment: Ok. I tried getActivity() with a Toast and that worked.

Comment: you will always use context with toast, after this line `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);` view contains all the views inside that layout so you need to access them with view

Comment: Gottcha! Thanks for clearing it

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.seek);
```

to

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek);
```

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. Can you explain why context didn't work?